# MySQL обрабатывает запросы в 100 раз медленее чем sqlite Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, база-данных

Первый сайт на Django я делал по видеоурокам,использовал sqlite3 локально, после того как я закончил делать сайт, я приступил к созданию своего сайта, подключил MySQL, переопределил регистрацию `auth_user` создал свою `main_user` больше я ничего значительного не делал, но страница на много медленее подгружается, подключил `debug_toolbar_Django` и результаты меня удивили, не могу понять от чего это зависит, может ли это быть из-за того что я использую MySQL на сервере?

[image: MySQL]

[image: sqlite3]

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто mysql находится не на вашем сервере, а где то очень далеко от него или сеть до него перегружена. Не могут такие простые запросы выполняться в mysql столько времени.

Comment: @Mike Да, mysql находиться ну у меня на сервере(Я в Германии) а во Франции, меня просто пугает на столько большие задержки, на счёт нагружености не знаю, могу ли я как-то это проверить? В любом случае спасибо за ответ, я уже знаю что это не я сильно накосячил в коде

Comment: Дайте с машины на которой у вас код, ping до сервера где база, думаю он вам покажет те же 50ms пути

Comment: Да, это задержка к базе данных, еще для теста переключился на sqlite3, и все запросы по 0.3-0.8 мс, спасибо